# change url of web browser thru command line?

Tags: command-line, browser

Is there some way to change the current url (of current tab or an specific tab) of a running web browser (any) thru command line?

It can be any browser that run on Linux, preferably if it is light weight.

I don't mean to close and re-open the browser.

I was only able to open new tabs on browsers but not change the current url of them. I could not fast and easily find ways thru qdbus either (not that there aren't).

If some plugin alows this also, it may be ok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) you can use [MozRepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) addon to control Firefox via telnet. For example, to change current url of a current tab to http://v4.ident.me:

```
(echo "content.location.href = 'http://v4.ident.me/'"; sleep 2) | telnet localhost 4242 > /dev/null
```

Comment: is it possible to exit without error from telnet? if mozrepl is not started it returns 1, if command is successful it returns 1!

Comment: check here the full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337292/can-we-exit-without-error-from-telnet-with-mozrepl

Answer (score 2):

install `mozrepl` on firefox:  [wiki](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki) , [Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/)

and install `fresno` tools in unix: [website](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Fresno)

then use it, (i.e.
Send your browser to a page: 
`./fresno -p http://google.com/` )

[more example](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Fresno)

Comment: fresno sounds interesting, may be less work than using the telnet option; I wonder when it will have a package for ubuntu at least on ppa?